# Java Script: How to ammend a datetime variable to set a specific time?

Tags: javascript

I need to take a datetime values from an MSSQL based app which is read into the script as 22/12/2010 3:56pm and adjsut the time component toa  set time.

I've used what I know of javascript and what I can find in google searches to try and progress this but to no avail.

Premis: I need to read the date time value and  set the time portion of the date to 8am, 1pm or 4pm dependent on another field.

The conditional logic portion of the script is fine the date functions aren't so fine.

Current code I'm currently using:

```
      if(fldPriority.Value=='2')
   {
    var ResDate = new Date(fldTargetResolutionTime.Value);
    var newdate = new Date(ResDate.getYear(),ResDate.GetMonth(),ResDate.GetDay(),16,0,0,0);

    objReturn = newdate
   }
```

Problem:
The date reads in originally in gmt format 22/12/2010 3:56pm but then gets changes to utc format and the date changes significantly to Wed Oct 12 15:56:00 UTC+12 2011

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using any server-side language? wich one?

Comment: The application supports javascript

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the Date and set the time using UTCHours.

The return value will be the correct Date and time,
but you if need to convert it to a string the string will be local time unless you call newDate.toUTCString();
(or objReturn.toUTCString())

```
var newdate=new Date(ResDate);
newDate.setUTCHours(16,0,0,0);
objReturn=newDate;
```

Comment: hmmm UTC dates are mega confusing, the date goes in at 23/12/2010 11:56 am and after the code you provided comes out as Sat Nov 12:05:00 UTC +12 2011

Comment: the local settings are for GMT + 12 long and short date format aligned to dd/mm/yyyy format